# Android & Appium(Java) : WebView inaccessible

Tags: java, android, webview, automated-tests, appium

I'm currently using Appium and have hit an issue with regard to finding the WebView context. Using UIAutomator I can inspect the WebView and see its child elements, however I cannot access any of these by using CSS selector/ XPATH because I cannot switch to WebView.

I have tried looping over driver.getContextHandles(), however this simply returns "NAVTIVE_APP".

Android version being used is 5.0.1 and the latest version of Appium.

Does anyone know of a way to find out the name of the WebView or possibly being able to switch to it?

Comment: Did the developers enable the WebViews debugging? Check if they called setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled in the code.

Comment: I've figured out a working solution to this issue.  Instead of trying to gather the element by an ID we used by Name instead and this returned the element we were trying to access. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the contexts....below is an example of handling Login with Facebook webview. It worked for me....

```
Set<String> contextHandles = driver.getContextHandles();
    for (String s : contextHandles) {
        System.out.println("Context : " + s);
//if context contains webview then set the webview context
        if (s.contains("WEBVIEW")) {

            //System.out.println("Set the Context NATIVE to WEBVIEW");
            driver.context(s);
        }
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='0']")).sendKeys(EMAIL);
    //System.out.println("UserName Entered");
    //sleep(3000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='1']")).sendKeys(PASSWORD);
    //System.out.println("Password Entered");
```